# CMake поиск библиотеки и if

Tags: cmake, gtest

Написан проект, в него добавлен gtest.
Собираю проект через cmake и столкнулся с трудностями.

Допустим, на другой машине gtest не будет и нет так таковой необходимости собирать тесты.

Сейчас CmakeLists.txt написан таким образом, что при отсутствии gtest проект собираться он не будет:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

Подскажите, каким образом через if можно проверить наличие пакета на компьютере с последующей сборкой целей.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (GTEST_FOUND)
  #...
endif (GTEST_FOUND)
```

Читайте документацию https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html